# I am trying to use the Google Analytics Add-on for Google Sheets but multiple filters are not working as expected

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

When I use the following filters in GA custom reports, it works fine:

[image]

But when I try to implement the same in the Google Sheets add on, using the following expressions:

> ga:pagePath=~/offer AND ga:pagePath!~/offer/\D+/\D+/

The result is coming as zeroes all the way. When I try ; (semi-colon) in place of AND, it gives me an error. When I try a comma, it works as expected (OR). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you give more details on all the dimensions and metrics you're trying to pull in GA custom reports as well as in google sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct filter you should use in the "filters" cell in Google Sheets is

```
ga:pagePath=~/offer;ga:pagePath!~/offer/\D+/\D+/
```

no spaces no anything. semi-colon is used for AND.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: That actually worked! I had been bugging over this for so long, and all for what - _spaces_? Wow. Thanks a lot.